# Style em lista desordenada

Tags: css, css3

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menuPrincpal {
}

.menuPrincipal li {
  display:inline;
}

.menuPrincipal li a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:19.6%;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgb(223,189,92);
}

.menuPrincipal li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color:rgb(223,189,92);
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menuPrincipal">
  <li>
    <a href="index.php">
      <img src="_img/_menuImgs/home.png"> Home      
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="catalogo.php">
      <img src="_img/_menuImgs/colecao.jpg"> Coleção      
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="contato.php">
      <img src="_img/_menuImgs/contato.png">Contato      
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="loja.php">
      <img src="_img/_menuImgs/loja.png"> Loja       
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="sobre.php">
      <img src="_img/_menuImgs/sobre.png"> Sobre      
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

A ideia é retirar os espaços `margim` e `padding` da `UL`. E ***ESTÁ*** funcionando quando faço:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menuPrincpal {
}
```

Mas quando faço:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.menuPrincpal {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

embora o `objeto` com `classe` `menuPrincpal` seja uma `UL`, ***NÃO*** funciona.

Porque?

Comment: Cuidado com a falta de atenção amigo

Answer (score 0):

Porque você digitou o nome da classe no CSS errado:

`.menuPrincpal`

É `.menuPrincipal` - faltou a letra **i**.

Comment: Por favor, me perdoe: cansaço! Olhei isso várias vezes e ví o 'i' alí. Obrigado!. Devo excluir a pergunta?

Comment: Nem... Deixa aí! Tá sussa... Todos passam por isso uma hora ou outra.

Comment: ok. Obrigado então!